Alternative ways to build LEGO engines
I can’t figure out how to make a Lego V8 engine without using the Lego-made parts. I don’t want to buy any parts, so I need alternatives. Any ideas?

Do you mean the typical technic pseudo-engine? I.e. the technic parts where pistons connected to a rotating crankshaft move up and down?

Yes, I do. I don’t have the dedicated Lego pieces for the purpose of the engine.

A simple way to build engines whitout using LEGO-made parts is this one for example in BL studio:


I am thinking it could be more compact, because I want to make a v8, and that wouldn’t really go well with a big, bulky design, and the pistons could be bigger.

maybe this link: https://rebrickable.com/mocs/?get_drill_downs=&q=v8%20engine

Yep! That works great.
